# Bootable disk not recognized by my laptop?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, boot-loader

I have an Asus ux303 laptop and I am trying to install ArchLinux on it.

I think I already have installed it on the harddrive, however BIOS will not even show the harddrive in Bootable options.

When I stick the iso usb I have and boot my computer from the usb and type

```
fdisk -l
```

I will see:

```
Disk /dev/sda 230Gb
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier ...

Device /dev/sda1
Boot *
Id 83
Type Linux
```

So I have a bootable partition I believe, where Arch Linux is installed, but when I remove the usb and restart the computer I find myself in the BIOS and in "Boot Order" there are no selection I can make.

Comment: At this point, I think it is safe to say your ArchLinux installation is hosed. Unless you are in dire need to rescue some data from that drive/partition. I would go ahead and reinstall it, paying more attention to the screen prompts. Arch, due to keeping the OS footprint small, leaves a lot of stuff we take fro granted, out. I have never been in your position but I wouldn't be surprised if the wrong install parameter is the culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one thing you haven't mentioned is whether that disk is structured with GPT or the old MBR style.  That would be very important.  But beyond that there may be Secure Boot issues

My ASUS (different model) was a pain to boot non-Microsoft stuff from USB or CD.  Maybe this affects booting from hard disk too ( have not tried that yet)

Basically I had to change a settings in the BIOS.

Disable "Secure Boot" in the Security tab

"Launch CSM" to  "[Enabled]" in the boot tab.

This guy https://superuser.com/questions/692821/how-to-boot-from-usb-on-asus-x551ca had other settings he had to change.  So your milage may vary,  but it seems like ASUS has made getting that CSM running the key.

Basically ASUS, post Windows 8.1, seems to be going one step more towards allowing Secure Boot to prevent owners from install the operating systems they choose.